# How to handle widows authentication dialog using webdriver in python

Tags: selenium2, python

I have an application which is secured by http authentication. So when I open the URL it is looking for user/pass in windows authentication dialog. I wanted handle this dialog to enter user/pass and click OK button to proceed further on web browser.

I tried with WebDriver by passing

```
br.get('https://user:pass@URL')
```

but it did not work. Any solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a non-browser popup that you have to provide your credentials into before navigating or is this a browser popup or is this just done behind the scenes based on your windows credentials?  Please provide the exact steps and preferably html/selenium code in the steps.

Comment: it is windows authentication dialog (this is non browser)  like when we click save button and see dialog. steps are ...  open browser, input url and enter, now popup would come to enter user/pass. Please let me know if more details needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is not able to interact directly with OS functionality.  So unless there is some backend service that allows you to create the connection through the browser somehow you can't use Selenium for this.

Options:

1. Write custom code to do this outside of selenium and then put it in the middle of your test
2. Utilize another testing tool at least for the login and then go back to Selenium.

Sikuli is a good tool for this type of thing.  You can execute your sikuli test command line via code and then roll into your test after login is successful.
http://www.sikuli.org/